# Seeking good examples of report data selection user-interface

Tags: user-interface, reporting

In an ongoing attemt to reinvent the wheel only when necessary, I am looking for good examples of user interfaces for data selection for reports.

I hope to see examples raising the bar above the following:

[Report selection example 1 http://www.durell.co.uk/Manual/Reports,%20Accounts,%20KPI%20Overview_files/image003.png](http://www.durell.co.uk/Manual/Reports,%20Accounts,%20KPI%20Overview_files/image003.png)

[image: Report selection example 2]
<sub>(source: [saptechnical.com](http://www.saptechnical.com/Tutorials/ABAP/DynamicSelect/Page1.12.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9f783224-9871-4eea-b1d5-f3140a253db6&displaylang=en

I like the UI.